# discord.py - How to create advanced join command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created a join command for my discord.py bot. The user can specify the channel where the bot will connect, or not specify it, and then the bot will connect to the channel to the user. But it doesnt works. There are no errors. It always sends "Error! Channel not found.".

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx, *channelname):
    if channelname is None:
        try:
            channel=ctx.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()
            await ctx.send("Joined!")
        except AttributeError:
            await ctx.send("Error! You are not connected to the channel available to me.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=channelname, type="ChannelType.voice")
        try:
            await channel.connect()
            await ctx.send("Joined!")
        except AttributeError:
            await ctx.send("Error! Channel not found.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your command such that `channelname = None`. In addition to that the type of the channel is an object not a string.

```py
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx, *, channelname=None):
    if channelname is None:
        try:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()
            await ctx.send("Joined!")
        except AttributeError:
            await ctx.send("Error! You are not connected to the channel available to me.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        channel = discord.utils.get(
            ctx.guild.channels, name=channelname, type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
        try:
            await channel.connect()
            await ctx.send("Joined!")
        except AttributeError:
            await ctx.send("Error! Channel not found.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```